# Adding a CNAME record in Cloudflare pointing to a Heroku hosted application

Tags: heroku, networking, dns, cloudflare, cname

I have a NodeJS application hosted on Heroku and I'm using Cloudflare to handle my DNS settings.

Unfortunately, the root domain for my application won't resolve since I don't have CNAME record pointing to it and correspondingly, I also receive the following error on my Cloudflare dashboard:

*`"An A, AAAA or CNAME record was not found pointing to the root domain. The XXXX.com domain will not resolve".`*

I found the relevant [documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/205893698) for Heroku-hosted apps (shown below) which explains that all I need to do is to add a CNAME record for my root and point it to the server name. (It also states why I can't point it to a static IP address)

[image]

**My problem is - how do I add a CNAME record pointing to the server name when the field I'm supposed to add the server name to only accepts an IP address?**

See below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Additionally, I'm further confused by the following piece of [documentation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169046-How-do-I-add-a-CNAME-record-):

[image]

Comment: In the Name field enter a `@` also check this: https://blog.cloudflare.com/zone-apex-naked-domain-root-domain-cname-supp/

Comment: @nbari thanks for the link to the blog - seems like adding a CNAME pointing to the root domain should be a breeze but its stumping me... i tried adding @ and it still doesn't allow me to add anything other than an IPv4 address in the second field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a browser issue with Cloudflare.

On **Firefox** this is what the CNAME input fields look like.

[image]

On **Chrome** this is what the CNAME input fields look like.

[image]

Comment: Switched from Safari to Brave; everything worked. 